# Using a sled on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, sport-athletics, snow

Assuming that there is a reliable *eruv*, are there any halachic issues with sledding on Shabbos?

Comment: what with גורר ועושה חריץ בפסיק רישא

Comment: @kouty Would that apply to snow (in which it should? serve no beneficial purpose and which is destined to melt)?

Comment: and the  known pb of  עובדא דחול?

Comment: Offhand, it sounds like it may be the same questions as bike riding on Shabbat. Some communities (esp. in Israel) allow it. Most don't. I suspect the main issue is that it's considered a "weekday" type activity. Offhand, I can't think of any direct melachotthat might be violated. Is there any concern of "smoothening" (memarech?) the snow by using the sled? There's no question that the sled flattens and smoothens the snow. What about any concern that the rope to the sled may tear?

Comment: סימן שא סעיף טז     קטע בשתי רגליו ומהלך על שוקיו ועל ארכבותיו ועושה סמוכות של עור לשוקיו יוצא בהם בשבת:   may be that this is a little similar so if sled is allowed,  no need to eruv.  but @DanF is right uvda dechol is the pb

Comment: I would include skiing in the same question. It sounds like it has similar problems (if there are any.) Of course, I'm referring to croos country skiing or downhill skiing itself, not riding the gondolla or T bar. Though, assuming that you didn't hav eto pay for the ride, that may not be a problem either, in terms of melacha. The gindolla and T-bar are also not stopping only for you.

Comment: For that mater, seems like any snow sport (except snow mobile - is that even a "sport"?) would  be in the same category - skiing, snowboarding, half-pipe, moguls and all the strange snow stuff you see in the Olympics. Probably ice skating too?

Comment: @DanF In regards to the rope I'm not really sure about the halach of tearing and whether it applies to rope. But the rope possibly tearing is clearly a davar sheino miskavin.

Answer (score 4):

According to Rabbi Elchanan Lewis on [yeshiva.co](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=1860) there is no problem in sledding on shabbos as long as there's an eruv.

Comment: However ,if it would be a sled used for actual travel then it would be uvdin dchol,it must be talking about a recreational sled,or children's sled