# May one do exercise on Purim?

Tags: purim, sport-athletics

Purim is a Jewish holiday - however, unlike other holidays almost everything is permitted granted it's in the "spirit" of the holiday.

With that being said is physical exercise permitted on Purim?

Answer (score -2):

The Shmirat Shabbat K'hilchata rules that you can do physical exercises on Shabat - so it follows kal ve'chomer that you can exercise on Purim.

Comment: Whooops. I had checked this and posted the results [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8416/is-exercise-on-shabbos-allowed/69676#69676). The Shmirat Shabbat Kehilchata writes **the exact contrary of what you state**. He writes (vol 1, p. 158) "**One should not, as a rule, perform physical exercises on Shabbat** or Yom Tov, whether with or without the use of an instrument designed for strengthening muscle"

Comment: You should add the exact citation and quote what it says specifically.

Comment: Besides what the previous commenters wrote, I don't understand the _kal vachomer_ argument. The question asked whether it's forbidden as being not "in the 'spirit' of" Purim. How does something being permitted on Shabas imply a fortiori that it's in the spirit of Purim? For example, eating is permitted on Shabas but not in the spirit of _tzom G'dalya_.